# Force text color in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, textcolor

I'm using TinyMCE to allow users to make comments on existing text, but we want the existing text to remain black, but have the comments typed in red.  I'm able to limit the color options to only have red with the textcolor_map option, but, even with this, the first character I type is still in black.  Is there a way to force any new text to appear in red?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TinyMCE is really just allowing you to edit an HTML document so the rules behind the colors you see rendered in the editor are tied to the CSS that you apply to the content.

The `textcolor_map` option you refer to has to do with the colors someone is allowed to pick via the color picker.  The color picker wraps the selected text in a `<span>` and applies the color you pick - so that won't really fix your issue.

If you want comments to have a different color from the original text you could wrap the comment in a `<span>` and apply inline styles or CSS to that element to change the color of the text to red.

You can either try to capture keystrokes and wrap them in  tags (not easy to get right) or you could use a toolbar button to "Add Comment" and then use a dialog to accept the text for the comment.  When you insert the comment you could then color it appropriately. You can also use `contenteditable="false"` to stop people from modifying the original text.

*(I see you work for PSC Group ... tell John Head I say hello!)*

Comment: Thanks!  We ended up going with the first suggestion, since we needed to be able to make inline comments.  We ran into an issue where formatting upon hitting the left arrow cause the left arrow to not always move the cursor left, but we got around that by just not formatting whenever the left arrow was pressed.  I have passed along your salutation to John.  Small world, eh?

Comment: If my answer works can you accept the answer?  That will help people know that the answer solved your problem and also stop others from taking the time to provide additional answers.

Comment: @KatieReynertson, could you share the solution with me, please?

Comment: @user9500574 Sorry, I no longer have access to this code base.